# .Net MVC3 resource file and multi-tenancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource, multi-tenant

I have learned much and solved a lot of problems coming up with multi-tenancy.
But one problem still exists. I have to offer a tenant-specific resource file because our customers want some text a little different then other customers.
Is there a way to implement a multi-tenant resourceManager? I haven't found anything else in the www.

Answer (score 1):

We needed the same functionality in a web forms project and ended up implementing our own IResourceProvider, finding inspiration in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx. That way we could have files like Default.aspx.rex, Default.aspx.da-DK.resx and Default.aspx.da-DK.xyz.resx, where xyz was the customer name. This worked quite well. Going this way seems to imply using the App_LocalResources and App_GlobalResources folders.

However, those folders are not the MVC way of using resources and will cause problems. For instance, they will not work properly with unit testing. As a last resort you might find it useful though.